# Save Alert text input into database from ionic alert

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, alert

I have created an ionic alert to decline a request. I want the user to input a reason for declining the request  before they hit confirm. I then would like to save this data into my database and have a method (declineRequest) setup to do so.

The method is working for declining the request. The issue is how to save the alert 'Notes' input field into the database, and how to make sure the declineRequest method is only run when 'confirm' is clicked.

Here is the code:

The HTML:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-card *ngFor="let r of requests; let i = index">
      <ion-item>
      <h2>{{r.userId}}</h2>
      <p>{{r.requestDetail}}</p>
      <p>{{r.fromDateTime}} to {{r.toDateTime}}</p>
      <p>{{r.type}}</p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-card-content>
            <button class="approve" ion-button icon-left color="secondary" (click)="approveAlert(r.id)">
              <ion-icon name="checkmark"></ion-icon>
              Approve
            </button>
            <button class="decline" ion-button icon-left color="danger" (click)="declineAlert(r.id)">
              <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
              Decline
            </button>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card> 
  </ion-list>
```

The TS:

```
declineAlert(requestId) {
const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Confirm Request Declined',
  subTitle: 'Notes:',
  inputs: [
    {
      name: "Note",
      type: "text",
      placeholder: 'Please enter reasons'
    }],
  buttons: [ { text:"Cancel"
  },
  { text: "Confirm",      
  handler: data => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); 
    console.log(data.Note);
  }
  }],
  cssClass: 'alertCustomCss'
});
alert.present();
console.log(requestId);
let notes = Note;
this.declineRequest(requestId, notes);
}
```

I have tried different methods but cannot seem to get the text from the decline 'notes' to save.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Keval pointed out you just need to use your method inside the handler like so:

```
declineAlert(requestId) {
  const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Confirm Request Declined',
  subTitle: 'Notes:',
  inputs: [
    {
      name: "Note",
      type: "text",
      placeholder: 'Please enter reasons'
    }],
  buttons: [ { text:"Cancel"
  },
  { text: "Confirm",      
  handler: data => {
      this.declineRequest(requestId, data.Note);
      // additional steps like pop() page etc
    }
  }],
    cssClass: 'alertCustomCss'
  });
  alert.present();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with my working code

```
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Confirm Request Declined',
  inputs: [
    {
      type: 'textarea',
      name: 'Message',
      placeholder: 'Please enter reasons',
    },
  ],
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Yes',          
      handler: data => {           
        var message = data.Message;
       //Here is Api call
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'No',          
      role: 'cancel',
      handler: data => {           
        var message = data.Message;
        //Your logic
      }
    }
  ]
});
alert.present();
```